# Groupby on second level index that respects the previous level

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to have two-level index, of which one is of type `datetime` and the other one is `int`. The time column I'd like to resample for `1min`, and the int column I'd like to have it as intervals of `5`.

Currently I've only done the first part, but I've left the second level untouched:

```py
x = w.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='time', freq='1min'), pd.Grouper(level=1)]).sum()
```

The problem is that it's not good to use bins generated from the entire range of data for `pd.cut()`, because most of them will be zero. I want to limit the bins only to the context of each 5-second interval.

In other words, I want to replace the second argument (`pd.Grouper(level=1)`) with `pd.cut(rows_from_level0, my_bins)` where `mybins` is an array from the respective 5 second group that's in intervals of 5. (e.g. for `[34,54,29,31] -> [30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55]`).

How `my_bins` computed can be seen below:

```
def roundTo(num, base=5):
  return base * round(num/base)

arr_min = roundTo(min(arr))
arr_max = roundTo(max(arr))
dif = arr_max - arr_min

my_bins = np.linspace(arr_min, arr_max, dif//5 +1)
```

Basically I'm not sure how to make the second level `pd.cut` aware of the rows from the first level index in order to produce the bins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go is to extract the level values, do some math, then groupby on that:

```
N = 5
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='datetime', freq='1min'), 
            df.index.get_level_values(level=1)//N * N]
          ).sum()
```

You would get something similar to this:

```
                          data
datetime            lvl1      
2021-01-01 00:00:00 5        9
                    15       1
                    25       4
                    60       9
2021-01-01 00:01:00 5        8
                    25       7
                    85       2
                    90       6
2021-01-01 00:02:00 0        9
                    70       8
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I noticed that after appending data, it would no longer be grouped (e.g. there'd be two `lvl1 = 60` index in your example). Do you know if there's some way to automatically re-sum according to the groups, or do I need to call `groupby` on the entire dataframe again?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean concatenate the outputs above from two different inputs? You can just do `out1.add(out2, fill_value=0)` instead of concatenation.